# Disable Scroll Zoom

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm having some problems with the scroll on my mouse (as soon as I touch the scroll button it scrolls up a couple of ticks) so in League of Legends, the problem makes me zoom in so much I can see the white in the eyes of the characters.

So is there a way to disable scroll-zoom in LoL? Another solution could be a key binding to zoom out via the keyboard.

EDIT: 
Its not in the Camera options. Drag Scoll is a key that you press to scroll the screen, and not a mouse scroll.

[image]

Ive added the line in both configurations and it did nothing.

[image]

Comment: Is this even possible? I don't really think so...

Comment: why not disable the mouse scroll altogether (from windows)?

Comment: Well I fixed the problem by replacing my mouse. But if I leave this open in case there's a solution that doesn't involve changing hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/66w5uc/disable_scroll_zoom/ :

Edit this file:

```
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\PersistedSettings.json
```

After the "shopEvent"block, to add this 'MouseSettings' setting

```
                {
                    "name": "MouseSettings",
                    "settings": [
                        {
                            "name": "RollerButtonSpeed",
                            "value": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

part to have that end of file:

```
                {
                    "name": "ShopEvents",
                    "settings": [
                        {
                            "name": "evtShopFocusSearch",
                            "value": "[Ctrl] [l],[Ctrl] [Return]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "evtShopSwitchTabs",
                            "value": "[Ctrl][Tab]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "MouseSettings",
                    "settings": [
                        {
                            "name": "RollerButtonSpeed",
                            "value": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a command called "Mouse Scroll" in key bindings (You have to be in game to do this and then click ESC) and its binding is "Mouse Button 3 (Mb3 or mouse button 3) Unbind this or bind it to something other than your wheel/Mouse button 3.

If that doesnt work you can also do this

Open this with Notepad:
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\input.ini

Paste this at the bottom:
[MouseSettings]
RollerButtonSpeed = 0

Comment: Have put the thing in input.ini, doesn't work. Also can't find Mouse scroll in the key binding.