# Re-enable mouse zoom in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

As per [this question and answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220328/disable-scroll-zoom), it's possible to disable mouse scroll in game. However, this not only stops the camera zooming in and out, but also disables the scrolling from working in the item shop.

I currently have the opposite problem, where the mouse scroll disabled itself in game on its own and I am unable to re-enable it despite deleting the config files, restoring defaults, even repairing the client. (It's not my mouse because scrolling works everywhere else, including the lobby, etc)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a good internet, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory/folder: `C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/Config/`
Open with your text editor: `PersistedSettings.json`
Search for: `RollerButtonSpeed`

You probably found something like:

```
{
  "name": "RollerButtonSpeed",
  "value": "0"
}
```

Change the value to 1.